# Windows 10 no internet access error after removing junk software

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, internet

I've googled around, seems like other have had variations of this problem, but none of the solutions have helped so far. I'm hoping someone might have some other insight for me.

The computer:
Asus Laptop with Windows 10 w/Anniversary Update

The story:
I'm visiting my mom for thanksgiving. She was getting popups on her laptop and overall weird stuff. I discovered She had 'accidentally' installed some various coupon software, there was still a bunch of Asus bloatware, and also had two 'meh' security software installed (McAfee AND Webroot). After removing all this stuff, the laptop was running MUCH better. In the process of removing the 2 security softwares, windows defender was turned on. As part of my normal computer cleaning routine, after everything was fixed, I rebooted the machine...Upon rebooting I got the dreaded "No internet error" for the wifi connection, all other devices were connecting to the wifi.

The Challenge: Below I will try and list in detail everything I have tried thus-far and give you all as much info as I can. There isn't much to backup, so if it was me I would have already nuked it. However, My goal is to NOT restore the computer, because we are out in the middle of nowhere and the only internet connection is a medicore metered 1mbps(120KBps) 4G connection, so downloading updates (espcially the service pack and productivity software) is gonna take forever and be costly for the data overages. I also tried the laptop on a separate wifi network (, same issue, no internet problem.

the wifi says connected but "unidentified network" and no internet connection

OK so here we go THE INFO:

The adaptor is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG. Driver issue is unlikey, since nothing changed with it and it was working fine. HOWEVER in device manage there is a WAN Miniport driver for every internet protocol (IKEV2, IP, IPv6, L2TP, Network Monitor, PPPOE, PPTP, SSTP). After booting into safemode all these WAN minports vanished. I'm curious if these are part of the problem, they are all generic microsoft drivers, and if i uninstall them, they automatically reinstall.

These solutions I've tried:

I've tried the windows 10 "Network Reset" function, no result.

I tried rolling back to a restore point, the computer would only boot to a black screen. So I undid the restore point roll back, and it boots again.

Disabled windows firewall and windows defender

safe mode with networking has the same problem

I've tried resetting the winsock stack, all the netsh reset stuff. I was getting a weird "access denied error" at the end of the winsock reset, so I changed the permissions in the registry editor for netsh as described here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3DpeeXLSDM) it got rid of the error, but still no internet.

Manually setting the DNS, Gateway and IP gets rid of the "unidentified network" message, but still no internet.

tried to use my phone as a USB tethered device, same issue, claims "unidentified network" connected but no ip address and no internet.

let me know if you need anymore info, and thanks in advance for the help....this is an annoying one!!!!!

results from IP config:

> ```
>     Windows IP Configuration
>
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ComputerName
>    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
>    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
>    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>
> Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-22-0B-03-14-E2
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-71-D9-6B-E4-48
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 6C-71-D9-6B-E4-48
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7594:3412:2339:5dba%17(Preferred)
>    Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.93.186(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 292319705
>    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-51-97-1D-AC-22-0B-03-14-E2
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                        fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{5ED3AF34-A60E-4B4B-95E3-D7715A029938}:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> ```

Comment: try checking to see if it added a vpn/proxy for you. If it did this, you wont be able to connect.  Start > Search for Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings button > uncheck all boxes except for for auto detect. Bs sure the proxy stuff is unchecked

Comment: Also, can you go to command prompt, run an `ipconfig /all` and paste that output in your post

Comment: @Narzard thank you for the response, see the ipconfig /all on the original post

Comment: Is there a working computer on the network that you can run ipconfig /all on to get the correct default gateway? Once you have that, I want to try disabling ipv6 and setting a static ip. Or, do you know what the default gateway is supposed to be?

Comment: @Narzard I tried that already, but I will again just to be sure. I did just discover in the windows event log NetBT gives me an error every time I try to connect. The Error is "Initialization failed becase the transport refused to open initial addresses" this error gets reported 2 times whenever connecting to the wireless (event ID 4307)...probally related. I need to run out for lunch right now, but I will be back soon. Thank you again for you help Narzard!!!!!!

Comment: You have enabled DHCP on interfaces, but no one get any proper ip...

Comment: @Narzard I'm rolling back to a restore point (not system restore, but restore point) right now to see if there is any luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DHCP Client service Running? It should be set to Automatic. If not try start it...
You can manually set IP, mask, gateway and dns (for test)...
I have similar problem fief years ago.
What help: I remove network device (in device manager) and install it again

Comment: DHCP client service is running, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: but you don't have proper ip and gateway ...

Comment: I know, that's the issue I'm having, it's is connecting to the access point, but is not getting an IP address, nor is the gateway resolving. If i manually apply it, it still does not work. I'm restoring the system right now to a restore point from a few days ago when it was working, lets see if that helps.

Comment: do you have any other devices on this network?

Comment: yes, another laptop (which i got the gateway number from) an iphone an an android phone. all are working fine. The problem happened after I removed McAfee + webroot security and windows defender turned back on. it was working until I reset the computer, and then it stopped work,.

Comment: ok, you set gateway, mask, dns like on other devices and unique IP from your lan, do you can ping gateway?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I have to give the lame answer...rolling back to a restore point fixed it. I hate not knowing what exactly got messed up, but luckily a rollback to a windows restore point worked. If anything it is a testament that the restore feature (windows restore point restore, not reinstalling the operating system) is super useful. Thanks for the help to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through that. Same thing happened with me. I tried every solution that Google gave but unfortunately nothing worked out. You'll have to refresh Windows 10 or try resetting it. 
After resetting, Windows will make a file on your desktop indicating which apps have been removed during the reset. 
It's the only thing that will help you. 
If you're resetting, then your personal files will not be harmed. 
Goto settings   >update and security

Comment: Performing a Reset seems like overkill.  This problem can be solved without a Refresh or Reset.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing helped me when I was stuck with this problem.

Comment: rolling back to a restore point from a week ago fixed it....super annoying. I hate not knowing what the problem is, but nothing else worked. I belive the problem was caused by removing webroot security software and turning on windows defender...but really, this shouldn't happen. The windows console didn't give me any clues...just a very strange problem. The lesson is, be sure to keep your windows restore points turned on.